# PHP Como recorrer array y encontrar nodos hijos de niveles infinitos

Tags: php, array

Tengo una duda muy grande de como recorrer un `array` creado desde un `JSON`, el cual tiene múltiples niveles llamados `children`, es para hacer una estructura de árbol. El dilema es que tengo que llegar a cualquier nivel y solo tengo para llegar al tercero, dejo el código para que alguien de buen corazón me eche una mano.

```
$json = '[{"id": 6}, {"id": 7, "children": [{"id": 10}, {"id": 9}]}, {"id": 11, "children": [{"id": 14, "children": [{"id": 15, "children": [{"id": 16}]}]}]}]';

    $arrCat = json_decode($json,true);


    print_r($json);
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($arrCat as $item) {
        $idIt = $item['id'];
        echo "<li>Nodo:$idIt</li>";
        /* Check if it has children */
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            /* Get the suffixes recursively */
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($item['children'] as $child) {
                $idChildren = $child["id"];
                echo "<li>Hijo:$idChildren</li>";

                if (array_key_exists('children', $child)) {
                    echo "otro!";
                }

            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Necesitas recursividad.

Comment: Hola alanfcm, soy novato, me puedes guiar por favor, es para crear un menú del array que genera jqueryui en sortable

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres utilizando una funcion recursiva asi:

```
<?php
$json = '[{"id": 6}, {"id": 7, "children": [{"id": 10}, {"id": 9}]}, {"id": 11, "children": [{"id": 14, "children": [{"id": 15, "children": [{"id": 16}]}]}]}]';

    $arrCat = json_decode($json,true);

function printUl($arrCat) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($arrCat as $item) {
        $idIt = $item['id'];
        echo "<li>Nodo:$idIt</li>";
        /* Check if it has children */
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            /* Get the suffixes recursively */
            printUl($item['children']);
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
    printUl($arrCat);


?>
```

Comment: Mil gracias, eres un crack!